# Do 'edit node' redirect via custom PHP code?

Tags: rules

I have a rule for returning users to finish creating a cck form. I need to 'Do' custom PHP code to redirect the user to editing/finishing their cck form (node limiter limits user to only one PPE content item). The following does not work:

```
function ppe_edit_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  global $user;
  $nid = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = :uid', array(':uid' => $user->uid))->fetchField();
  drupal_goto('node/' . $nid . '/edit');
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you verify that the function gets called, for example by having it print something then exit?

Comment: @richardg thanks for the suggestion. I added a phpinfo(). A message in the same Do gets set, but the function does not seem to get called. If I add phpinfo(); all by itself, it prints. If I strip the func and only have the mid three lines, I get white screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the right code, or at least code that works:

```
$nid = db_result(db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = %d', [account:uid]));
$_REQUEST['destination'] ='node/' . $nid . '/edit';
```

Comment: this one is D6 code, the first was D7. But I think `[account:uid]` should be `$user->uid`.

Comment: "[account:uid]" is used in PHP code run inside a rule action, and it is replaced with the user ID of the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ppe_edit_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  global $user;

  $nid = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = :uid', array(':uid' => $user->uid))
    ->fetchField();

  drupal_goto("node/$nid/edit");
  exit;
}
```